# java HtmlUnit cookies and Apache cookies - compatible?

Tags: java

I need to make the cookies from `org.apache.http.cookie.Cookie` compatible with cookies from `com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.util.Cookie`.

Can you use those 2 cookies interchangeably? If not, how can I store both of those types of cookies within the same container?

Answer (score 0):

The [HTMLUnit's `Cookie`](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/util/Cookie.html) has methods to convert itself to a Http Client Cookie.

See [`public Cookie(org.apache.http.cookie.Cookie c)`](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/util/Cookie.html#Cookie%28org.apache.http.cookie.Cookie%29) to construct the HTMLUnit Cookie from the Apache one and [`Cookie#toHttpClient()`](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/util/Cookie.html#toHttpClient%28%29) to convert it back.

There also are static [`Cookie.toHttpClient()`](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/util/Cookie.html#toHttpClient%28java.util.Collection%29) and [`Cookie.fromHttpClient()`](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/util/Cookie.html#fromHttpClient%28java.util.List%29) methods to do this in batch.